# Tweepy streaming in MongoDB with full_text

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, pymongo-3.x

I need help to develop Python code, working with the library Tweepy and MongoDB. I cannot stream Tweets with full text. I don't know how to implement this code to this aim.

Please look at this code:

```
keywords = ['trump']

language = ['en']

analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):


    def on_status(self, status):
        if hasattr(self, status):
            try:
                tweet = status.retweted_status.extended_tweet["full_text"]
            except:
                tweet = status.retweeted_status.text
        else:
            try:
                tweet = status.extended_tweet["full_text"]
            except AttributeError:
                tweet = status.text



    def on_data(self, data):

        t = json.loads(data)

        tweet_id = t['id_str']  
        username = t['user']['screen_name']  
        followers = t['user']['followers_count']  


        tweet = unidecode(t['text'])
        text = t['full_text']            
        hashtags = t['entities']['hashtags']  
        dt = t['created_at']  
        language = t['lang']  


        blob = analyzer.polarity_scores(tweet)
        sentiment = blob['compound']


        created = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')

        tweet = {'id':tweet_id, 'username':username, 'followers':followers, 'text':text, 'hashtags':hashtags, 'language':language, 'created':created, 'sentiment':sentiment}

        print (username + ':' + ' ' + text)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            print (status)
            return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    stream = Stream(auth, l, tweet_mode="extended")



    tweets = stream.filter(track=keywords, languages=language )
```

I've tried to do it in a bad way.. For example, I replaced text with `full_text`, but it doesn't work. I hope you can help me..
Thanks for you time!

Answer (score 0):

`if hasattr(self, status):` will raise a `TypeError`, as [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) requires a string input for attribute names.

You should refer to [Tweepy's documentation on extended Tweets](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extended_tweets.html), which has [an example](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extended_tweets.html#examples) very similar to what I think you're trying to do.